# proof of limit using epsilon-delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Im trying to prove If $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = 100$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = \infty$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} (f(x) + g(x)) = \infty$ using epsilon-delta

$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = \infty \iff \forall C \: \exists\delta_1 > 0, \: 0<|x-a| <\delta_1 \implies g(x) > C $

$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = 100 \iff \forall \epsilon >0 \: \exists \delta_2 > 0, \:  0<|x-a| <\delta_2 \implies |f(x) - 100| < \epsilon $

Comment: What have you tried? What does your intuition say?

Comment: I let h(x) = (f+g)(x) and wrote the definition of $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} h(x)$ and chose $\delta = min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$

Comment: And what can you do next? Don't give up so easily! I think you'll be able to make a lot more progress if you put your mind to it.

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} h(x) \iff \forall M > 0 \: \exists \delta > 0, \: 0< |x-a| < \delta \implies h(x) > M $

$$M < 100 + \epsilon + C$$

Comment: You're right that $lim_{x\to a}h(x) = \infty$ if and only if for all $M$ there is a $\delta$ with that property. So can you see how to construct such a $\delta$ given an $M$?

Answer (score 1):

I'll follow up from my comments with a more complete hint at a solution.

Before we delve into the formal proof it's important to see intuitively *why* the statement is true. The point is that eventually we can be sure $f(x) > 0$ (because $100 > 0$). Then adding it to $g(x)$ only gets us a *bigger* number, so we're certainly still tending to infinity!

As you pointed out, to show that $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x) + g(x)) = \infty$ we need to prove the statement:

For all $M$ there is some $\delta >0$ so that if $|x-a| < \delta$ then $f(x) + g(x) > M$.

Recall our intuition. We want to get to a point where $f$ is positive. Luckily we can do that! Pick $\delta_1$ so that if $|x-a| < \delta_1$ then $|f(x) - 100| < 100$. In other words this means that if $|x-a| < \delta_1$ then $0 < f(x) < 200$.

We also want $g$ to get large enough that it becomes bigger than $M$. We can also do that. Since $g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to a$, there is a $\delta_2$ so that if $|x-a| < \delta_2$ then $g(x) > M$.

Now, see if you can put these results together to finish the proof.

The key takeaway is this: it's perfectly fine to plug values in to the epsilon-delta definitions! In fact, it makes proofs much easier.